# How to Get only division result between two numbers without modulas in php

Tags: php, division

```
$a = 100;

$b = 40;

$result = $a/$b;

echo $result;
```

for this the result is shown as 2.5 but i want it to be as 2

How to remove division result in this

Comment: Thanks to all for help me !! and thanks to stackoverflow for give a wonderful platform for solving programming problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can give

```
$a = 100;
$b = 40;

echo floor($a/$b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code. In PHP, you need to use function `intval()` to convert float to integer.

```
$a = 100; 
$b = 40; 
$result = intval($a/$b); 
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast the result to an integer (natural number) by using the `intval` function.

```
$a = 100;
$b = 40;
$result = intval($a/$b);
echo $resulk;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use floor function http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php

```
$a = 100;
$b = 40;
$result = floor($a/$b);
echo $result;
```